# use footnotesize when it's redefined by some template

Tags: fontsize

I am submitting a paper to a conference proceeding. The proceeding's template redefines `\footnotesize` to `\small` as

```
\let\footnotesize\small
```

Is there a way to use the actual footnote size in the paper? I have a big table and I want to reduce the space it consumes.

```
\begin{table*}[tb]
{\centering\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
...
```

I tried `\tiny`, which works for both text and inline math. But `\fontsize{6pt}{8pt}` does not. The font size of inline math is changed but the text stays at `\small` size. Perhaps the text font size is locked somewhere in the template?

Comment: In a line above `\let\footnotesize\small`, write `\let\origfootnotesize\footnotesize`; then you can access the 'original' size with `\origfootnotesize`.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work with the publisher -- they will certainly use their template to compile my tex source...

Comment: By "template," I presume you mean .cls file and not .sty file?

Comment: Yes, it's cls file

Comment: What is the template's `\documentclass`? From there you can figure out what font size it loads by default (most likely 10pt). Then you can manually extract `\footnotesize` from [`size10.clo`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/size10.clo). That may be overkill, as using `\fontsize{8}{9.5}\selectfont`.

Comment: @Werner Ah I see, thanks! Didn't know that I should add a `\selectfont`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the template's `\documentclass`, you can figure out what font size it loads by default (most likely `10pt`). If it loads a default `10pt` as the normal font, then you'll note it loading a file `size10.clo` (perhaps). You can manually extract `\footnotesize` from [`size10.clo`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/size10.clo).

Alternatively, if you can intervene in the template's loading, you can `\let\savefootnotesize\footnotesize` before the template overrides it, allowing you to use `\savefootnotesize` wherever you need the original `\footnotesize`.

Finally, if all else fails, `\fontsize{8}{9.5}\selectfont` should change the font to something similar to `\footnotesize` (for a `10pt` normal font document).